# Conda envs in different regions have different versions of dependencies

Tags: python, deployment, conda, dependency-management

When I install a `conda` package to four different regions (development through production), each `conda` environment ends up with different versions of dependencies.

Does anyone know why this could be happening or what I can do to prevent it? I don't want to fix every version in my `meta.yaml` because most of the modules are dependencies of dependencies. I thought that one of the benefits of `conda` was that dependencies would be settled at build time and I could count on those versions being the same all the way through production. Is that not the case, or is it likely my company's servers that are the problem?

Comment: What versions of conda are installed on each part of the process? If they're not the same, that could be one reason for the differences.

Comment: I have 4.6.14 installed to dev, and 4.6.12 in the other three regions.

Comment: If you install those versions of `conda` on your local computer, can you reproduce the dependencies that are installed on the remote machines?